# Есть ли в Python аналог JS конструкции "?."?

Tags: javascript, python

В `JavaScript` есть конструкция `foo?.bar`, когда при обращении к несуществующему полю объекта возвращается `null`
Существует ли подобное в `Python`?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, в пайтоне есть None, она возвращает тоже самое что и null

Comment: А давно оно в js? Это не Typescript?

Comment: @vp_arth, довольно давно, в районе года, если не больше

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Синтаксической конструкции нет. Но вы можете использовать функцию [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#getattr), чтобы добиться такого же поведения:

```py
bar = getattr(foo, 'bar', None)
```

А у словарей существует метод [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```py
foo = {}
foo.get('bar')
```

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите чтобы такое поведение имел ваш класс, то можно реализовать метод `__getattr__`:

```
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return None

print(A().bar)
```

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, я не могу вспомнить чего то похожего в питоне
Но здесь есть такая прекрасная штука, как тернарный оператор. Достаточно красиво выглядит и легко запоминается

```
if variable is None: print 'Is None' 
if variable is not None: variable.property
variable.property if variable is not None else None
```

Comment: Если у `variable` не будет атрибута `property`, то возникнет `AttributeError`